# Mingw64 and Python 3.12.2 conflict in VS code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, mingw-w64

I have installed Python 3.12.2 but in pygame program it shows `no module found pygame` even though I have installed Pygame using pip(with installed Mingw64)

I have checked after the uninstallation of Mingw64 the program works properly.

In cmd when I type `python --version` it shows `3.12.2` without mingw64 on system but with installed Mingw64 it shows `3.11.8`.

In environmental variables python scripts and exe paths are before mingw64/bin path.

Comment: Have you looked into using virtual enviornments?  Create a virtual environment using your Python 3.12.2 install, and install the pygame package in the virtual environment.
As for why it's picking Python 3.11.8 with Mingw64 installed, I'm guessing it has to do with the order of the install directories in your `PATH` system environment variable

Comment: @nisakova Please avoid code-formatting words that are not code, e.g. Python 3.12.2. Stuff like `python --version` is fine, though.

Answer (score 0):

Use the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> --> `Python: Select Interpreter` command in vscode to select the python environment.

If you are using a virtual environment, a new terminal will automatically activate the environment, installing `pygame` for your current environment. you will also need to use the official extended **Python** executable. This will use the correct interpreter.